# mv: cannot move 'standard' to 'CLI': Permission denied

Tags: windows, command-line, cygwin

In Windows 10, I have installed Cygwin. In cmd, I want to move a directory to under another:

```
>mv standard CLI
mv: cannot move 'standard' to 'CLI': Permission denied
```

I ran the mv command while a pdf file under `standard` was opened by a pdf viewing program. 
Then the mv command was hang, and I closed the pdf viewing program, but mv continued to hang.

I closed the cmd window, and I still couldn't move the directory in either cmd or folder explorer.

Restarting Windows doesn't solve the problem.

How can I solve the program?

Comment: permissions issue would be my guess. try running cmd as admin

Comment: Can you create a new folder in CLI\?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run PDF viewer program again and open any PDF file outside of that `standard` folder. Many programs keep continue holding access to the last opened file even it was close (may be for the purpose to show it in recent files, or indexing...). You may try also to spot this issue with help of [ProcessExplorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) that can show opened file descriptors for particular program.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried ProcessExplorer. But how can I identify the process which uses the specific pdf file?

Comment: Use the "Find handles" option.

Comment: Don't look for the PDF: look for the folder name - there may be other processes that are using the folder, eg as working directory.

Comment: Type  the path to that `standard` folder in "Find handles" in ProcessExplorer. (path to that folder could be partial. ) It should  list processes that took that folder